# EF delete entity with unloaded navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-4.1, navigation-properties

I have an Entity. `Mandate`. Every mandate has a required:many relation to a Person (NavigationProperty). I use the DbContext API with (LazyLoadingEnabled, AutoDetectChangesEnabled, ValidateOnSaveEnabled, ProxyCreationEnabled)

Now I like to delete a Mandate entity. The mandate entities are loaded by another context with `AsNoTracking()`.

```
message.Result.
    ObserveOn(On<DataComposition>.Scheduler).
    Where(r => r).
    Subscribe(_ =>
    {
        using (var unit = UnitOfWork.Begin())
        {
            var mandate = this.SelectedItem.OriginalEntity;

            this.mandateRepository.Attach(mandate);
            // mandate.Person.ToString();

            this.mandateRepository.Delete(mandate);

            unit.Commit();
        }

        this.List.RemoveOnUi(this.SelectedItem);
    });
```

Now during committing I get the following exception: `Entities in 'CodeFirstContainer.Mandates' participate in the 'Mandate_Person' relationship. 0 related 'Mandate_Person_Target' were found. 1 'Mandate_Person_Target' is expected.`

The delete works if I include the Person Property during the population/selection or if I visit the Property (lazyloading), but I **DONT LIKE** to materialize/hold many entities only for the deletion case and I **DONT LIKE** to trigger more than a single `DELETE` query to db!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that, if you have the navigation property `mandate.Person` populated, the following SQL statement ...

```
delete [dbo].[Mandates]
where (([Id] = @0) and ([PersonId] = @1))
```

... is sent to the database, lets me think that the navigation property indeed *must* be populated with a person with the correct `PersonId` to delete the parent.

I have no idea why Entity Framework just doesn't send a delete statement with the primary key ...

```
delete [dbo].[Mandates]
where ([Id] = @0)
```

... as I had expected.

**Edit**

If the `Mandate` entity has a foreign key property `PersonId` for the `Person` navigation property, the expected SQL (the second above) is sent to the database. In this case the `Person` navigation property can be `null` and the value of the FK property `PersonId` doesn't matter.

**Edit 2**

If you don't want to introduce a FK property the way with the least DB-roundtrip-costs would probably be to fetch the person's Id and then create a dummy person with that key in memory:

```
// ...
var personId = context.Mandates
    .Where(m => m.Id == mandate.Id)
    .Select(m => m.Person.Id)
    .Single();

mandate.Person = new Person { Id = personId };

this.mandateRepository.Attach(mandate);
this.mandateRepository.Delete(mandate);
// ...
```